# How to create page items with dynamic action defined on other item in page in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page with multiple text fields and select lists with the list of values. What I want to do is defining a dynamic action on one of the select lists that display numbers and returns same numbers and according to the selected number, I want to create or duplicate another select list in an amount of selected number. Then, after the end-user finish his work, I want to be able to take the selected values of select lists that are created within the dynamic action within the on-submit process.

Example:

[image: Screenshot of the page]
In short, I want to create a dynamic action that duplicates the instructor list as many as the selected number of the number of sections list. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are saying, you'd rather switch to a **tabular form** (or interactive grid, depending on Apex version you use). Using it, you can "Add row" as many times as you want (which would be your "Number of sections") and use the same LoV (i.e. Select List) in every row.

As far as I know (which really isn't that much), Apex isn't capable of doing that "as is". *Maybe* you can accomplish it the way you want it using some other techniques (blindly guessing & mentioning: JavaScript, Ajax, jQuery or whatever you might need).